# Resources for writing ROS plugins

Tags: gazebo-1.4, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I realize that standalone Gazebo/ROS integration (among many other things) is something being worked on as we speak.

I still have a question relating to the Fuerte integration [question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1241/gazebo-ros-fuerte-integration/) . I would've commented but I think my karma's too low :) .

Regarding the comments about how the "joint_states" publisher is really a plugin that talks to ROS, I would like to put together a plugin or set of plugins to re-create some of the basic functionality provided with previous versions of ROS/Gazebo.

An example would be something like the erratic robot with controller, ideally launchable from a roslaunch file as well. I have seen gazebo_ros_ plugins but the examples seem to be for the earlier wrapped versions of Gazebo.

I would like to avoid starting from scratch if I can avoid it, so are there any resources implement the necessary plugins required for basic ROS robot controller functionality? Even a list of the required plugins would be helpful. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1334/resources-for-writing-ros-plugins/) by [phil0stine](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/130/phil0stine/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-02-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-02-11**:
+1 Since it never hurts for posters who have done their homework and write clearly to have some karma  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Not sure it will work for Fuerte, but in Groovy there is a bunch of plugins which work both in Gazebo 1.3 (groovy's version) and 1.4.

So, what I did so far is:

1. Install standalone Gazebo 1.4.
2. Adjust `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH` to point to `pr2_simulator/pr2_gazebo_plugins/lib`, `simulator_gazebo/gazebo/lib` and `simulator_gazebo/gazebo_plugins/lib` in Groovy `stacks` dir.
3. Add `<plugin>` entry to model/world SDF.
4. Add `-s` command-line parameter to load system plugins such as `gazebo_ros_api_plugin`.
5. Spawn a `robot_mechanism_controllers` controller with `pr2_controller_manager`.

With this setup I can run `robot_mechanism_controllers/CartesianWrenchController`, for example.

Hope it helps.

Boris

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) with karma: 330 on 2013-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/130/phil0stine/) on 2013-02-12**:
Thanks for the details, I will try to give it a shot in Fuerte and see if it works. Otherwise, groovy it is.

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/30/dejanpan/) on 2013-02-13**:
Hi there, we are running ROS plugins in fuerte with Gazebo hg version deprecated_parser_sdf_1.2_support, which to our understanding is actually 1.3 version. We have slightly patched the and gazebo_ros_paths_plugin.cpp script to find and load the ros plugins correctly. Drop me an email and I'll email you back patches until they get accepted upstream.

**Comment by [ffurrer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28/ffurrer/) on 2013-02-13**:
I created a pull request (https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/291/added-clearmodelpaths-and-addmodelpaths/diff), such that you can now set all paths (including the model paths) via ROS manifests (. The patch for the gazebo_simulator ROS stack can be found in the comment there.

usage in a ros manifest: e.g.


<gazebo gazebo_model_path="${prefix}/models"/>

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-02-14**:
@ffurrer: Great! Will it work with catkin's `package.xml`?

**Comment by [ffurrer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28/ffurrer/) on 2013-02-14**:
@Boris: I don't know, you will need to try that ;)